# Can I impersonate through the whole session?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, session, impersonation

I have an mvc4 web application where users log in using their roaming profile user accounts. I authenticate them through the `Active Directory`. And in almost all methods I need to impersonate the logged in user to make some file operations.

I use following methods for the impersonations:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int LogonUser ( string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out IntPtr phToken );

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int ImpersonateLoggedOnUser ( IntPtr hToken );

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int RevertToSelf ();

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int CloseHandle ( IntPtr hObject );

private IntPtr lnToken;
```

I have implemented my impersonater as an `IDisposable` class and in `constructor` I impersonate and in `Dispose` method I revert back to the user that was on before my impersonation. So I can use it in a `using` statement easily in my controller methods like this:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction ( string param )
{
    using ( new Impersonator( username, password, nameSpace) )
    {
        /// do staff
    }
}
```

This approach works just fine, though I figured that this slows down the response time of website for about 1.5-2 seconds and I find this a little annoying.

What I am wonderin is can I make the impersonation when user logs in and revert back when logs out or their sessions time out? In other words can I keep an impersonation alive through the session?

I might not be using the correct terminology, sorry about it.

Comment: Are you able to let IIS (assuming you're using it) handle the authentication?  We do this with our app, and IIS then also handles the impersonation for you - the whole request is then run in the context of the user

Comment: Yes I run my website under IIS. But is it possible for IIS to impersonate differently on each login? OR are you talking about the identity of the application pool in IIS?

Comment: Yes, each user will be impersonated individually.  At that point, things are running in their security context rather than that of the app pool

Comment: Okay, this sounds interesting. So where should I start?

Comment: [Here's a start](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730708(v=ws.10).aspx) but specifics on configuring it are a bit beyond the original scope of this question :)

Comment: We use it in conjunction with Windows Authentication, and as a fallback if needed, Basic Authentication

Comment: okay, let me take a look at it ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63409/discussion-between-tolga-evcimen-and-james-thorpe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to, I would recommend using IIS to perform both the authentication and impersonation for you in this scenario.  If you:

- Enable [ASP.NET Impersonisation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118(v=vs.71).aspx)
- Disable Anonymous Authentication
- Enable [Basic Authentication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772009(v=ws.10).aspx) (if you have clients from outside the domain)
- Enable [Windows Authentication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628(v=ws.10).aspx) (if you have clients within the domain)

When people request a page from the site, IIS will issue an HTTP 401 Challenge to the browser.  If it's located within the same domain and the browser supports it (IE and Chrome do automatically), the current user will automatically log on to the site.  If they're outside of the domain, the browser will present a login box for authentication.

Note that if you're using Basic Auth, credentials are sent in plain text, so it's important to have a properly secured https connection.

Once authenticated with IIS, only then will the request get to .Net - at which point it will be running in the security context of the user, rather than the app pool.  Note that a call to:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

will show the impersonated user.